# A clean way to identify $\nabla(|f|^2)$ with $2f\overline{f'}$ for a holomorphic $f$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \Bbb C$ be an open domain and $f\colon \Omega \to \Bbb C$ be a holomorphic function. By identifying the point $z = x+iy$ with $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$, we may write $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ where $u,v$ are real-valued functions on $\Omega$ (considered as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$). We can then define a real-valued function
$$
W(x,y) = |f(z)|^2 = u(x,y)^2 + v(x,y)^2.
$$

It is not hard to verify that $W$ is differentiable and its gradient is
$$
\nabla W = 2\begin{bmatrix}
uu_x+vv_x \\
uu_y + vv_y
\end{bmatrix}
=2\begin{bmatrix}
uu_x+vv_x \\
-uv_x + vu_x
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where we used the Cauchy-Riemann equation to substitute $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$. Again, by the Cauchy-Riemann equation, we know that $f'(z) = u_x(z) + iv_x(z)$ and hence
$$
f\overline{f'} = (u+iv)(u_x-iv_x) = (uu_x + vv_x) + i(-uv_x + vu_x).
$$
One would be tempted to identify the real gradient of the real-valued function $W$ with the complex number $2f\overline{f'}$ and write
$$
\nabla W(x,y) = 2 f(z)\overline{f'(z)}.
$$

> Is there a neat way to derive this "identity" $\nabla W = 2 f\overline{f'}$?

Of course, this looks suspiciously like the identity $(g^2)' = 2gg'$ for a differentiable $g\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, but with a complex conjugation sign, so I think it is reasonable to expect that one should be able to derive it using a product rule or chain rule of some kind.

I tried writing $W = f\bar f$, thinking of $f,\bar f$ as $\Bbb R^2$-valued functions, and then differentiated it. Alas, I am quite bad at complex analysis and couldn't recover the desired identity. One of the problems I encountered is that the $2\times2$ Jacobian matrix $D(\bar f)$ cannot be identified with $\overline {f'}$. In fact, $D(\bar f)$ doesn't even represent any complex number (since $f$ is holomorphic). By that I meant the identification of $\Bbb C$ as isomorphic to the subalgebra of $M^{2\times 2}(\Bbb R)$
$$
\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
a &-b \\
b &a
\end{bmatrix}  : a,b \in \Bbb R \right\} \cong \left\{ z = a+ib : a,b \in \Bbb R  \right\} \cong \Bbb C. 
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you identify $\nabla W$ with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}W + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}W $
then you can use the [Wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives)
$$
{\begin{aligned}{\frac {\partial }{\partial z}}&={\frac {1}{2}}\left({\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}-i{\frac {\partial }{\partial y}}\right)\\{\frac {\partial }{\partial {\bar {z}}}}&={\frac {1}{2}}\left({\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}+i{\frac {\partial }{\partial y}}\right)\end{aligned}}
$$
which satisfy a product rule like a “normal” derivative. For holomorphic functions is (because of the Cauchy-Riemann equations)
$$
\frac {\partial }{\partial z} f = f' \, , \,\frac {\partial }{\partial \bar z} f = 0 \,,\\
\frac {\partial }{\partial z} \bar f = 0 \,, \,\frac {\partial }{\partial \bar z} \bar f = \overline{f'} \, .
$$
Then
$$
\nabla (|f|^2) = 2 \frac {\partial }{\partial \bar z} (f \bar f)
= 2 \left( \bar f \frac {\partial }{\partial \bar z} f  + f \frac {\partial }{\partial \bar z} \bar f \right) = 2 f \overline{f'} \, .
$$

Comment: Now it looks so natural, thank you very much! I know about the Wirtinger derivatives, but I don't have an intuition about when one should use it. Could you recommend an article/a book that would be helpful in understanding the Wirtinger derivatives more?

Comment: @BigbearZzz: I am sorry but I do not have recommendations.

Comment: No problem, the answer is already very nice as it is. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This may help or it may not ... :) Recall that the exterior derivative is a real operator, so $d\bar f = \overline{df}$.
\begin{align*}
d(|f|^2) &= d(f\bar f)= fd\bar f + \bar fdf = f\overline{df} + \bar fdf = f\overline{f'dz} + \bar f(f'\,dz) \\&= (f\overline{f'})d\bar z + (\bar ff')dz
= (f\overline{f'})(dx-i\,dy) + (\bar ff')(dx+i\,dy) \\
&= \big(f\overline{f'}+\bar ff'\big)dx + i\big(\bar ff'-f\overline{f'}\big)dy
=2\,\text{Re}(f\overline{f'})dx - 2\,\text{Im}(\bar ff')dy \\ &= 2\big(\text{Re}(f\overline{f'})dx +\text{Im}(f\overline{f'})dy\big).
\end{align*}

Comment: It does help, thank you! May I also ask which book I should pick up to read about some complex manifolds? I do have knowledge of standard smooth manifolds and Riemannian manifolds, but very little about things like this. I am sure I have seen $d\bar f = \overline{df}$ somewhere, but it does not come naturally to me. I've read a tiny bit of Hormander's "An Introduction to Complex Analysis in Several Variables" a few years ago for a certain reason, but I think it's not a place to start learning about this kind of thing.

Comment: Can you give me a little guidance on where you’d like to be headed? Chern, R.O. Wells have some excellent older books. These days, many people look at Huybrechts’s text.

Comment: I'm not really heading for anything to be honest, I just think that knowing a bit more about this topic would be nice. I have background in analysis of PDEs and the calculus of variations, and so far I've managed to get through without knowing much of complex analysis or complex manifolds. I feel that it'd be a shame to not know anything about it, considering that it looks really beautiful.

Comment: My main comment is that you need to progress past the stage of reducing questions about holomorphic maps or complex-valued maps in general to real and imaginary parts. The Wirtinger operators are the natural start. There's a lot of beautiful interplay among sheaf cohomology, Dolbeault cohomology, and PDE methods.

Comment: Sounds great! May I have the names of Chern's books you mentioned as well? I managed to find the book by Huybrechts but your comment suggested that Chern had a few interesting books.

Comment: No, just one on complex manifolds (“without potential theory”).

Comment: Thank you very much!